# "Key does not exist" exception thrown. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, exception, encryption, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have the below test which isolates a problem I'm running into using System.Security.Cryptograph.RSACryptoServiceProvider.  The problem is that r.Decrypt is throwing exception "Key does not exist".  If I use privateKeyXml for both the encryption and decryption (instead of using publicKeyXml when decrypting) then it works as expected.  Of course I do not want to share the private key, I need to be able to decrypt with the public key.
  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    [Fact]
    public void BasicEncryptDecrypt()
    {
        var cspParameters = new CspParameters() { Flags = CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey | CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt };

        string privateKeyXml = null;
        string publicKeyXml = null;

        using(var r = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParameters)){
            r.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            privateKeyXml = r.ToXmlString(true);
            publicKeyXml = r.ToXmlString(false);
        }

        byte[] encrypted = null;
        string decrypted = null;

        using (var r = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParameters))
        {
            r.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);
            encrypted = r.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foobar"), false);
        }

        using (var r = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParameters))
        {
            r.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);
            decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r.Decrypt(encrypted, false));
        }

        Assert.Equal("foobar", decrypted);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to decrypt an encrypted text using RSACryptoServiceProvider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763741/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-text-using-rsacryptoserviceprovider)

Comment: Don't forget how asymmetric encryption works: you always encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key.

Comment: yep, this is a dupe.  thanks

Comment: What I really want to do is use the private key to sign the document such that the public key can be used validate where it came from.

Comment: It looks like RSACryptoServiceProvider SignData/CheckData are what I should have been using.  Thanks.

Comment: For those who came from Google. This code example signs and verifies data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signdata?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 2):

You are using a "private key encryption / public key decryption". I'm working in a project where there's a specific context where we need do it. I know that there is a lot of discussions about this, but I will go on to explain how to do it. I think there are a lot of questions where it explains when we should use "sign/verify" or "public key encryption / private key decryption" or not.

First of all, I also got the same solution as you but it didn't work, I tested a lot of CspParameters options. I think it should work, but it doesn't!

So, my final solution was to use the BouncyCastle libraries:

```
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKeyParameters = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(prvKey));
AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKeyInfoParameters = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(pubKey));
byte[] clearData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("...");
string algorithm = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";

var cipherOne = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.CipherUtilities.GetCipher(algorithm);
cipherOne.Init(true, privateKeyParameters);
byte[] signedData = cipherOne.DoFinal(clearData);

var clientTwo = CipherUtilities.GetCipher(algorithm);
clientTwo.Init(false, publicKeyInfoParameters);
var clearDataTwo = clientTwo.DoFinal(signedData);

Assert.IsTrue(Convert.ToBase64String(clearData) == Convert.ToBase64String(clearDataTwo));
```